# How to fwd urls to existing paths AND one more path with apache's mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current .htaccess looks like this:

```
        RewriteEngine On
#       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_project
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
        RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The uncommented lines are pretty straightforward:

- The two `Cond`s make sure the `Rule` isn't applied to existing files (`!-f`) and folders (`!-d`).
- The `Rule` sends **everyting else** to index.php

The uncommented lines I took from somewhere. I believe it's the best way to do what I require: 'pretty urls'.

Basically it works. Existing files (e.g. `/css/general.css`) are requestable and non-existing paths (e.g. `/admin/login`) are routed to index.php. **Existing and non-existing paths must be able to work 'amongst eachother': `/css/all.css` is sometimes a buffered existing css file and sometimes (when it doesn't exist) it's handled by PHP. `/css/general.css` is always a file. `/css/club_N.css` (N is a number) is always a PHP script.**

`/_project/` is an existing folder with Basic HTTP Auth protection. For instance `/_project/phpinfo.php` works as well. In  the `_project` folder I have created a (valid) symlink to the backups folder: `/_project/backups/`. Somehow the (existing) files in the backups folder can't be reached. For instance `/_project/backups/today.bz2` is routed to index.php =( The same happens with either or both commented lines uncommented.

What's wrong with the htaccess config? If I remove the Rewrite stuff entirely, I get a `403 Forbidden`. Probably something with the `.htaccess` in the `_project` folder (?).

PS. Obviously I can't show you the actual website. People wouldn't like it if you could download their backups =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess` files are hierarchical in scope, any such files in parent directories apply to their children.

The Basic Auth in `/_project/` will apply to subdirectories unless you switch it off in those directories, as will the `RewriteRule` declaration.  Often it is wise to add `RewriteEngine off` in the `.htaccess` of the child directory structure to stop the rules applying there, or possibly add a conditional blocking that structure on the original rule set.

Comment: You might be right, but that's not the issue. The HTTP Auth **should** work through all subdirs (the backups shouldn't be available without auth). The HTTP Auth isn't the problem. The rewriting is. The backup folder isn't found/recognized by Apache.